# TYPO3 login BE user via code

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

TYPO3 version 7.6.18. How login BE user via code ? Is it possible? Help me please.

may be something like that ?

```
if(empty($GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user['uid'])) {
            $login = new StandartLogin();
            $login->login($username, $password);
        }
```

but it works fo FE user

Comment: you will find code for backend login in typo3/sysext/backend/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the extension `simulatebe` is enough for you.

It can automatically create a backend login when a frontend user logs in: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/simulatebe/Introduction/Index.html